# Weird lines in Cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to make a cake stand. Here is what it looks like:
[image]

And here is it in wireframe:
[image]

The thing is, when I use a reflective material, I can see these lines running along the face of the cylinder and I can't seem to get rid of them (I've tried adding additional edge loops to no avail):

[image]
[image]

To be specific, I'm talking about the lines that kind of look like the old Japanese flag:
[image]

What are these and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: What happens if you select the faces within that ring, and hit `F` to merge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is causing pinching artifacts in this mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18637/what-is-causing-pinching-artifacts-in-this-mesh)

Answer (score 3):

This is called pinching. This happens because you have single vertex with a lot of edges.

[image: Pinching]

You can improve it by deleting the vertex and adding a n-gon in the middle.

[image: wireframe]

This is not ideal solution in every case because there is the n-gon in the middle but for rendering it works quite well.

Comment: .. you could grid-fill after an inset, if you wanted all quads.